# Cannot use table 'DeviceCodes' for entity type 'DeviceCode' since it is being used for entity type 'DeviceFlowCodes'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I am using ASP.NET Core 5 (version `5.0.100-rc.2.20479.15`); Visual Studio Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview - Version 16.8.0 Preview 6.0; Mircosoft SQL Server 2019; Entity Framework Core; ASP.NET Core Identity Server; Blazor web-assembly.

Libaries

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0-rc.2.20475.17" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0-rc.2.20475.17" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.0-rc.2.20475.17" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer" Version="5.0.0-rc.2.20475.17" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0-rc.2.20475.6" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.0-rc.2.20475.6" />
</ItemGroup>
```

When application don't query anything to database, it work ok. When I login, has action to database, it catch error.

In file `ApplicationDbContext.cs` , I have call base constructor from base class

```cs
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-CA6GPT5;Database=foo;User Id=fooUser; Password=SeCrET;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    // ...
}
```

In database, I have

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'DeviceCodes' for entity type 'DeviceCode' since it is being used for entity type 'DeviceFlowCodes' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'DeviceCode' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity typed mapped to 'DeviceCodes'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IReadOnlyList<IEntityType> mappedTypes, string tableName, string schema, IDiagnosticsLogger<Validation> logger)
```

Detail

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'DeviceCodes' for entity type 'DeviceCode' since it is being used for entity type 'DeviceFlowCodes' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'DeviceCode' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity typed mapped to 'DeviceCodes'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IReadOnlyList<IEntityType> mappedTypes, string tableName, string schema, IDiagnosticsLogger<Validation> logger)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger<Validation> logger)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger<Validation> logger)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger<Validation> logger)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IModel model)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IModel model)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IModel model)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder+<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<T>(IServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Set<TEntity>()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore<TUser, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserLogin, TUserToken>.get_UsersSet()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore<TUser, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserLogin, TUserToken>.get_Users()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore<TUser, TContext, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserLogin, TUserToken>.FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<TUser>.FindByNameAsync(string userName)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.V4.Pages.Account.Internal.LoginModel<TUser>.OnPostAsync(string returnUrl)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert<T>(object taskAsObject)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'DeviceCodes' for entity type 'DeviceCode' since it is being used for entity type 'DeviceFlowCodes' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'DeviceCode' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity typed mapped to 'DeviceCodes'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IReadOnlyList`1 mappedTypes, String tableName, String schema, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Set[TEntity]()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6.get_UsersSet()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6.get_Users()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6.FindByNameAsync(String normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.PasswordSignInAsync(String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean lockoutOnFailure)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.V4.Pages.Account.Internal.LoginModel`1.OnPostAsync(String returnUrl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert[T](Object taskAsObject)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Looks like the Entity `DeviceFlowCodes` is already pointing to the Table `DeviceCodes` can you please check or share the entity attributes for the involved entities

Comment: How to check `DeviceFlowCodes` point to table `DeviceCodes` ? This table generated automatic by ASP.NET Core Identity Server.

Comment: are these tables created by Identity Server?. I thought these were generated by your application.

Comment: Yes, these tables belong to ASP.NET Core Identity Server.

Comment: @Saravanan this is my source code https://github.com/donhuvy/acc133 . I temporary make it public for you diagnostic issues.

Comment: looks like this is a java project you have shared

Comment: I am sorry . https://github.com/donhuvy/a133 . I also add SQL script for you import to DBMS

Comment: your model also has a class called as DeviceCode in https://github.com/donhuvy/a133/blob/main/Server/Models/DeviceCode.cs#L7 if the code is in IdentityServer, then it should be coming from the nuget package right, also the same is in the DBContext https://github.com/donhuvy/a133/blob/main/Server/Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs

Comment: @Saravanan Let's post your answer. Your comment is true. It works now.

Comment: As part of the nuget package, the CreateIdentitySchema.cs file already contains the migration to create Devicecode https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/search?q=DeviceCode

Comment: Please revoke the git access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment of [@Saravanan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541917/saravanan) is exacty. `DeviceCode` is belong to ASP.NET Core Identity Server . When generate data code, I did not remove it, it was a mistake

```cs
public virtual DbSet<DeviceCode> DeviceCodes { get; set; }
```

and

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceCode>(entity =>
{
entity.HasKey(e => e.UserCode);

entity.HasIndex(e => e.DeviceCode1, "IX_DeviceCodes_DeviceCode")
    .IsUnique();

entity.HasIndex(e => e.Expiration, "IX_DeviceCodes_Expiration");

entity.Property(e => e.UserCode).HasMaxLength(200);

entity.Property(e => e.ClientId)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(200);

entity.Property(e => e.Data).IsRequired();

entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasMaxLength(200);

entity.Property(e => e.DeviceCode1)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(200)
    .HasColumnName("DeviceCode");

entity.Property(e => e.SessionId).HasMaxLength(100);

entity.Property(e => e.SubjectId).HasMaxLength(200);
});
```

Solution: Remove these above lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

I see ApiAuthorizationDbContext. It seems to me ApiAuthorizationDbContext has DeviceCode  table too and you trying to replace ApiAuthorizationDbContext DeviceCode entity with your entity. Change the name your DeviceCode table

Comment: yes, looks like somehow it is duplicated in the code